# Why are primary keys and unique constraints disappearing from tables?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, constraints

We are using Django with PostgreSQL on Heroku. We have tables with primary keys and unique constraints (created with class Meta / unique_together in Django). But the problem is, we found at least a few times that tables don't have primary keys and unique constraints - they disappeared for unknown reasons.

Does anyone know why the constraints disappeared? We didn't get any error messages but there were duplicate values in the tables where the unique constraints should have prevented them. The primary keys and unique constraints just disappeared.

What happened and how do we prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Well, PostgreSQl its self sure won't do that! So you're looking somewhere in your application stack. Making sure you retain detailed logs (`log_statement = ddl`, at least, and probably CSV mode logging) will help you diagnose future issues. Make sure to change the defaults for log retention!

Comment: I don't think our application alters the tables. I think they are altered during maintenance.